# MATLAB/.NET Interop -Setting property on a .NET object is not allowed

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, interop

I am writing a DLL in C# which is intended to be used from [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) R2011a using the native .NET interop. I have run into a situation where I am not able to set the value of one of the properties on my object.  Here is a simple example:

```
namespace MatlabTest
{
  public class Container
  {
    public int Value { get; set; }
  }

  public class MatlabDll
  {
    public MatlabDll()
    {
      this.Prop = new Container();
    }

    public Container Prop { get; private set; }
  }

  public class MatlabDllChild : MatlabDll
  {
  }
}
```

Now, I can access the property on objects of type `MatlabDll` from MATLAB just fine:

```
NET.addAssembly('MatlabTest.dll');
myObj = MatlabTest.MatlabDll();
myObj.Prop.Value = 5;
```

However trying to set the same property on an object of type `MatlabDllChild` fails using

```
myChild = MatlabTest.MatlabDllChild();
myChild.Prop.Value = 5;
```

Error message:

> Setting the 'Prop' property of the 'MatlabTest.MatlabDllChild' class is not allowed.

Why does MATLAB allow me to set the property on the base class but not the derived type?

Comment: I think MatLAB legacy .NET framework loader searches for the properties using Reflection, and does not include inherited properties in a queue when scripting, that is why workaround using a temporary object works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Because it has a private setter and those aren't available to Derived Types.

For Example:

```
public class Base
{
   private string baseString = "";

   public string BaseString { get { return baseString; } }
}

public class Child : Base
{

}
```

There is no way to access the set, which is effectively what you have done.

If you need the set to available to derived types use [`Protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx) instead.

```
public Container Prop { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: I'm not trying to set `Prop` at all.  I'm trying to set a public property on `Container` which has a public setter.

Comment: @heavyd but you're modifying Prop which causes the prop setter to be raised.

Comment: is this a behavior specific to the Matlab interop?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your example, and although I couldn't assign the property directly, using another (reference) object worked just fine:

```
myChild = MatlabTest.MatlabDllChild();
tmpObj = myChild.Prop;
tmpObj.Value = 5;
disp( myChild.Prop.Value )
```

Perhaps this is a bug/limitation in the MATLAB .NET Interface...

Comment: I think MatLAB legacy .NET framework loader searches for the properties using Reflection, and does not include inherited properties in a queue when scripting, that is why workaround using a temporary object works perfectly.

Comment: @ArturMustain: I don't claim to know the internals of MATLAB .NET Interface, but I doubt that is the case: when I changed the accessor of the setter from `private` to `protected`, the error went away..

Comment: Might have to do with how Matlab, as a pass-by-value language, parses chained .-references. On regular Matlab values or objects, `foo.bar.baz = 5` is not parsed as a get on `foo.bar` and then a set on `.baz` of the result; it's parsed as a set on lvalue `foo.bar`, and foo's `subsasgn` method decides internally how to handle the chained `.baz` argument. Maybe interaction with .NET property inheritance is affecting how Matlab is parsing the `myChild.Prop.Value = ...`. Amro's temp variable could work around this because myChild.Prop is only an rvalue there and only a get is attempted on it.